# Django - Transform an address in latitude and longitude through Google API and save the object

Tags: django, api, google-maps, django-models

I have an Address model where I save the address in different fields:

- address_1
- address_2
- zip_code
- city
- country
- latitude
- longitude

First, I ask the user to fill a form with the address (without latitude and longitude, by default they are set to "0"). Then I try to convert this address into latitude and longitude using Google API before saving the object.

Here is my code. I don't know if it's the right way to do it but right now it doesn't work and I get the error

> 'float' object has no attribute 'save'

Any idea how to solve this issue?
Many thanks in advance.(I'm new to programming and new to Django)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from users.models import Profile
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
import requests


class Address(models.Model):
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    address_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    zip_code = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    country = CountryField(blank=True)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, blank=True, default='0')
    longitude = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, blank=True, default='0')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Adresse de {self.profile.user.username}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "addresses"

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        super().save(**kwargs)

        address = " ".join(
            [self.address_1, self.address_2, str(self.zip_code), self.city])
        api_key = "PROJECT_API_KEY"
        api_response = requests.get(
            'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={0}&key={1}'.format(address, api_key))
        api_response_dict = api_response.json()

        if api_response_dict['status'] == 'OK':
            self.latitude = api_response_dict['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
            self.longitude = api_response_dict['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
            self.save()
```

Comment: You should probably use this at the end of your definition: super().save(**kwargs)

Comment: @vctrd your comment solved the problem :) many thanks. I read also that it's better to create a utils.py file for this kind of function. That's the next step!

Answer (score 3):

As @vctrd pointed out, I should have placed super().save(**kwargs) at the end of my function. Now it's working.